# Invoking Clojure from Java in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, clojure

I installed La Clojure Plugin for IntelliJ Idea IDE so I'm either able to use Clojure REPL, or create a Clojure app, but how to run a Clojure function from a Java program? For some unknown reason, I can't `import clojure.lang.RT;` etc. Can you give me a step-by-step guide so it will be possible to invoke Clojure code from Java?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to have the clojure jar in your dependencies (they are shown in Project Tab -> External Libraries).

Comment: It depends. Either add clojure<version>.jar to your modules dependencies manually or add the dependency to your build script and recreate your project files. RT.jar is from java sdk.

Comment: I tried to do like this. I went to `Project Structure [Ctrl+Shift+Alt+s] -> Modules -> Dependencies -> Add (+) -> Library -> Java -> C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 3.1.3\lib\clojure.jar`  and chose to add `clojure.jar` as a `Module Library`. And `clojure` appeared in the `External Libraries` of the Project. Was it the correct way?

Comment: Yes, now I can successfully `import clojure.lang.RT;`! But there's a problem No 2. I downloaded Mikera's `clojure-utils-master` in a zip format (without any jars). How can I start using it?

Comment: Since it's a maven project, executing mvn package should be enough to get a jar...

Comment: Have a look at the maven docs: https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html. It should be easy enough.

Comment: Christian, thanks a million! I've already found a compiled jar, added `clojure-utils.jar` using the same way I did and successfully evaluated `Object result = mikera.cljutils.Clojure.eval("+ 1 2");` inside a main java method. I'll read maven docs too to check out what this is, thank you for the link!